# How to go back to UiTabBar home page from UiTableViewController that is loaded upon button click from a button within the homepage tab?

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, uitableview, uinavigationcontroller

i have created a universal tabbed iOS application in Swift 2.0, the application has 3 tabs in the first tab, in the viewcontroller in storyboard i have placed a button upon which when pressed a UiTableView is loaded and it has a feature to add cell (a note taking feature embedded within the app), my issue is that once the UITableViewController is loaded i cannot go back to the previous page, its like this:

I have a TabBarController linked to a NavigationController which is linked to a HomepageViewController and When button is clicked, NavigationController linked to UITableView which shows ItemDetailViewController

My problem is that once i get to the UITableViewController i cannot go back to the home tab - HomeViewController

I have tried adding a UiBarButton to the top left of the UITableController and using poptorootviewcontroller , but it didnt work, any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to my understanding, your tabbar controller is at the root of window. You can access it as self.window.rootviewcontroller. After that, you can use tabar.selectedIndex to switch tabs.

Comment: I want to get to the first tab bar by clicking the left UIBarButtonItem in the tableview

Comment: [tabbar setSelectedIndex:0]; should do that.